# Angular2 pass data to another component on click of a button

Tags: angular, material-design

I have list of tasks being displayed in the UI using ngFor.

How can I pass data to another page when I click edit in the following. It has to pass the data corresponding to the datacard on which the Edit button is clicked.

```
<div *ngFor="#task of tasks">
    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand mdl-color--teal-300">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{task.taskname}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
        {{task.taskdesc}}
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">                
        <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">{{task.assignedto}}</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Mark Completed</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">EDIT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What data do you want to pass on what click?

Comment: when I click the Edit button, I want to display a page where I can edit the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data to the another page on click of some button than you have to use routing first, then pass the required data as
`RouterParams` at the time of routing like this :-

```
<div *ngFor="#task of tasks">
    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand mdl-color--teal-300">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{task.taskname}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
        {{task.taskdesc}}
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">                
        <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">{{task.assignedto}}</a>
        <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Mark Completed</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/Edittask', {data: task.taskname}]" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">EDIT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

than at the receiving end use `RouteParams` to get the values that you send on the button click. see here for more about RouteParams.

- https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html

<kbd>[Working Example of ROuting with Params](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKSnUzM4aLg1Q8ftkFAp?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, It works. But how do i pass multiple fields ? I did `<a [routerLink]="['/EditTask', {data: task.taskname, data2: task.taskdesc}`  .. it works, but doesn't seem like an ideal way to it.

Comment: if you have two or three values to pass than its okay, you can do using this method, but if you have array or Object to pass using `RouteParams` than you can use common service to transfer data because there is no way to pass Object/Array using RouteParams according to officials, `RouteParams` only suppors string yet, see here  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.htmlhttps://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html